# Lavravel não encontra o arquivo para download

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho uma rotina no projeto onde anexo documentos mas não consigo de forma alguma que a Storage encontre o mesmo.

Este é o meu método de download:

```
public function download($id)
{
    $anexo = PendenciaAnexo::where("id", "=", $id)->get()->first();        

    Storage::download(PathController::pathPendAnexos($anexo->pend_anexo_file_path));
}
```

Este é um outro método que utilizo para configurar um caminho para quando estou em desenvolvimento e quando estou com o projeto em produção na rede:

```
public static function pathPendAnexos($file_path)
{
    if(ConfigController::modeOfDevelopment() == "production"){
        return '/storage/pend_anexos/'.$file_path.'';
    }else{
        return '/storage/public/pend_anexos/'.$file_path.'';
    }
}
```

Arquivos no meu projeto:

** caminho absoluto dentro do projeto

**C:\laragon\www\LogisticSupportX\public\storage\public\pend_anexos**

** na pasta storage:

**C:\laragon\www\LogisticSupportX\storage\app\public\public\pend_anexos**

Já tentei de tudo com vários caminhos possíveis e absolutos mas nada funciona, sempre esse mesmo erro:

**File not found at path: storage/public/pend_anexos/PEND_80_ANEXO_4.pdf**

Mas os arquivos estão lá!!

Comment: Existe uma pasta chamada storage dentro da pasta public? Caso esteja em diretórios separados você pode criar um link simbólico para a pasta public apontar para storage

Comment: php artisan storage:link >  vide doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Na verdade essa storage é o link simbólico, mas não entendo porque não encontra se o cadastro de produto eu utilizo algo similar com o mesmo caminho mas com pastas distintas!

Comment: Esta é a de produtos: return '/storage/public/produtos/'.$file_path.'';

Answer (score 0):

Quando você busca um arquivo no `Laravel`, ele vai partir sempre da pasta `public`, como você está guardando na `storage`, é necessário apenas voltar uma pasta antes de tudo. Segue exemplo:

```
public static function pathPendAnexos($file_path)
{
    if(ConfigController::modeOfDevelopment() == "production"){
        return '../storage/pend_anexos/'.$file_path.'';
    }else{
        return '../storage/public/pend_anexos/'.$file_path.'';
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu essa mensagem agora: Path is outside of the defined root, path: [../storage/public/pend_anexos/PEND_80_ANEXO_4.pdf]

Comment: Quando coloco apenas um ponto dá a mesma mensagem de antes

Comment: @UlissesGimenes você consegue anexar o seu arquivo `config/filesystems.php` na pergunta?